# Unable to extract the contents of a web page using Beautifulsoup with html.parser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page from Fidelity Investments using a Python script. I have a problem with Beautifulsoup which I am unable to solve after many attempts.

**My code:**

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    newResult = soup.find_all("span", class_="account-selector--tab-row account-selector--account-balance js-acct-balance ")
    print(newResult)
    try:
       print(newResult.contents)
    except:
       print("Failed newResult.contents")
```

**Result that I get:**

```
    [<span class="account-selector--tab-row account-selector--account-balance js-acct-balance ">
        $3,980.00</span>]
    Failed newResult.contents
```

**My question:**

How do I get the `$3,980.00` into a string variable/object.

I have tried many methods, but failed to extract anything from `newResult`. For example, I have tried to print `newResult.text`, `newResult.string.strip()`, `newResult.getText`, `newResult.get_text`, `newResult.contents`, `newResult.stripped_strings` all within try blocks. All of them have resulted in code execution from the except block.

**Note** that `newResult` contains a newline and several invisible tab characters. I don't know if that makes a difference. Any help will be appreciated as I am at my wits end.

Comment: newResult[0].text as it is a list Or better still, use find not findAll so only single soup tag returned then you can just use .text without index

Comment: you are most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

`soup.find_all()` creates a list of `span` elements that matches your selection and you can not access the the contents directly.

### How to fix?

Option#1 - Iterate over your `newResult` to get the texts of each `span`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
newResult = soup.find_all("span", class_="account-selector--tab-row account-selector--account-balance js-acct-balance ")
print(newResult)
for item in newResult:
    try:
       print(item.get_text(strip=True))
    except:
       print("Failed item.get_text(strip=True)")
```

Option#2 - If it is only one element that you wanna get, use `find()` instead of `find_all()`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
newResult = soup.find("span", class_="account-selector--tab-row account-selector--account-balance js-acct-balance ")
print(newResult)
try:
    print(newResult.get_text(strip=True))
except:
   print("Failed item.get_text(strip=True)")
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. As you can see, I am still a newbie to this. I am very grateful to you for reaching out so quickly.